# Does V8 have Unicode support?

Tags: v8, unicode-string

I'm using v8 to use JavaScript in native(c++) code. To call a Javascript function I need to convert all the parameters to v8 data types.
 For eg: [Code to convert char* to v8 data type](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1String.html)

```
char* value;
...
v8::String::New(value);
```

Now, I need to pass unicode chars(wchar_t) to JavaScript.

First of all does v8 supports Unicode chars? If yes, how to convert wchar_t/std::wstring to v8 data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this was the case at the time this question was asked, but at the moment the V8 API has a number of functions which support UTF-8, UTF-16 and Latin-1 encoded text:

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/include/v8.h

The relevant functions to create new string objects are:

- String::NewFromUtf8 (UTF-8 encoded, obviously)
- String::NewFromOneByte (Latin-1 encoded)
- String::NewFromTwoByte (UTF-16 encoded)

Alternatively, you can avoid copying the string data and construct a V8 string object that refers to existing data (whose lifecycle you control):

- String::NewExternalOneByte (Latin-1 encoded)
- String::NewExternalTwoByte (UTF-16 encoded)

Answer (score 0):

Unicode just maps Characters to Number. What you need is proper encoding, like UTF8 or UTF-16.

V8 seems to support UTF-8 (v8::String::WriteUtf8) and a not further described 16bit type (Write). I would give it a try and write some UTF-16 into it.

In unicode applications, windows stores UTF-16 in std::wstring. Maybe you try something like

```
std::wstring yourString;
v8::String::New (yourString.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code did the trick

```
wchar_t path[1024] = L"gokulestás";

v8::String::New((uint16_t*)path, wcslen(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't have unicode support, the above solution is fine.